# How to know which method started a Worker Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm developing a c# multithreaded application since some years. A few days ago I've noticed that, while it runs, it continuously creates new worker threads (almost once per second). Using Visual Studio 2013 "Threads" window these threads have No Name and Location is "not available", so I cannot check where these threads start. 
I gave a name to all threads generated in my code, but still these threads are created with "no name" so I guess that they may be generated by an external assembly.

My application integrates NLog.dll (for logging into txt files), System.Data.SQLite.dll (for data reads and writes to db3 databases). It also uses UDP and TCP sokets for data exchange.

**Example:**
After 2 minutes of application running I have 70 threads. Then, after 20 minutes the number of threads is 190!!! If I check Threads window in Visual Studio I see that all new threads ahave "Category" "Worker Thread" and "Name" is "No Name".

Here a snapshot of my Visual Studio Threads window:

[image: snapshot of my Visual Studio Threads window]
Can anyone suggest me how to find the origin of this threads flooding?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is not in your code, you can only strip down your project to find the root cause (if it is a 3rd party library). Another possibility would be some anti-virus tools, which will inject .dlls into created processes to check them and sometimes going mad especially while your developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try Process Monitor from SysInternals toolkit (www.sysinternals.com/).
ProcMon has a filter for thread activity events.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of threads (with Name "No Name" and Location is "not available") are created by `Timer` object (in my case `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`). The thread flooding was caused by this line of code:

```
timerUpdateStatus.Change(0, 0);
```

that was called in the `Tick` event handler and then resetted back to the correct value by another call to `Change` method:

```
timerUpdateStatus.Change(statusUpdateTime, 0);
```